# Ошибка с array_key_exists

Tags: php, warning

Имеется это:

```
function checkUserExists($value, $has_by_tag = true) {
    $Values = getDB()['dl_users'];
    if ( $has_by_tag ) {
        foreach ( $Values as $User ) {
            if ( $User['username'] == $value ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return array_key_exists($value, $Values);
    }
}
```

Ошибка с полем:

```
return array_key_exists($value, $Values);
```

Ошибка:

```
[06-Apr-2021 10:21:57 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/fastuser/data/www/fffffffffffff/Functions.php on line 164
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: можно сделать так чтобы `$Values` был массивом, а не `null`. именно об этом вам пишет варнинг пхп.

Comment: @teran можете пожалуйста дать готовый код?

Comment: какой вы хотите увидеть от меня код, если у вас `getDB()['dl_users]` равен `null` ?

Comment: зачем перебирать всех юзеров? не проще сделать выборку по 1 юзеру? не очевидные имена переменных!!

Comment: надо в ужасе выкинуть весь этот код, включая функцию getDB(), купить учебник, желательно Котерова, и потихоньку начинать осваивать программирование и работу с БД.

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkUserExists($value, $has_by_tag = true) {
$Values = getDB()['dl_users'] ?? [];
if ( $has_by_tag ) {
    foreach ( $Values as $User ) {
        if ( $User['username'] == $value ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} else {
    return array_key_exists($value, $Values);
}
}
```

Так можно решить эту проблему